# Math formula For: Distance between center-points on a line.

Tags: geometry

I apologize in advanced for this simple question. Is there a formula for calculating; the Distance between center-points of known objects on a line? (read the example below for a better explanation.)

> For example: I am building a wall and the Bottom plate is 100 cm. Now I want to add 5 Wall Studs on this Bottom Plate. (These wall studs are 5 Cm in thickness). We need 2 of these in each end of the bottom plate and 3 to be placed with equal distance in between each other.

In this case the distance between all of the Wall Studs are 18,75 cm. Is there a quick way to determine this distance?

Here are some images that could be to some help.

[Reference Image for building a Wall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2sr8.png)

[My Calculations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oulDn.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Let $L$ be the length of the bottom plank. If you want to have $n$ (including the two at the ends) wall studs, each being $a$ thick/wide, with distance between the edges of the wall studs $b$, we have

$$L-2a=a(n-2)+b(n-1),$$

which we can solve for $b$ to get
$$b=\frac{L-an}{n-1}.$$

If you want the distance between the centers of the wall studs (call this distance $b'$), simply add $a$ to the result above, giving

$$b'=\frac{L-a}{n-1}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there there are $n$ studs of thickness $y$ equally spaced over a distance $x$. The distance between the centre of the studs is given by

$$ \frac{x - ny}{n-1} + y = \frac{x-y}{n-1}.$$

Note that this gives the same result as your calculation. Hope this helps!